# Woocommerce: get_title() product titles which include an ampersand getting cut off in mailto body link

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, mailto

Hoping someone can help. I am using `$_product->get_title()` to get the product title and outputting onto the page and also into the body= section of a mailto link. This is outputting correctly in both **except when there is an & ampersand in the title** e.g. :

'Hoses for TDI, TDC & TDCI vehicles'

In this case the body of the email just outputs up to the & and no further:

'Hoses for TDI, TDC'

I have tried various encodes. urlencode has got me closest and now outputs:

'Hoses+for+TDI,+TDC+&+Tdci+vehicles'

I now can't replace the + symbols with spaces!!? Hopefully fairly simple for someone?

```
if ( ! $_product->is_in_stock() ) {
        $productName = $_product->get_title();
        $productSKU = $_product->get_sku();
        $availability['availability'] = __('Please <a href="mailto:emailaddress?subject=Stock Enquiry&body=Availability request for: '.urlencode($productName).' ('.$productSKU.') please?">email us</a> for availability', 'woocommerce');
    }
```

Comment: Use `rawurlencode` instead. That replaces spaces with `%20`, and those should work fine.

Comment: Sorted it! Thanks.